# About the statement in the EventBus documentation?

Tags: greenrobot-eventbus

i am a beginner of EventBus. I tried to understand the statement in documentation with my program. But it doesn't like what you said in the documentation.

[Documentation as follows](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/delivery-threads-threadmode/)：

> ...... For example if you post another event in an event handler with MAIN thread mode, the second event handler will finish before the first one (because it is called synchronously – compare it to a method call). ......

my code as follows:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMainOrderMsgEvent(MainOrderMsgEvent event) {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new OtherMsgEvent("Other Msg"));
    Log.e(TAG, "onMainOrderMsgEvent: " + " finished");
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onOtherMsgEvent(OtherMsgEvent event) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onOtherMsgEvent: " + " finished");
}
```

it should be like this:

```
01-26 13:51:59.801 32643-32643/liufushihai.project.threadmode E/MainActivity: onOtherMsgEvent:  finished
01-26 13:51:59.801 32643-32643/liufushihai.project.threadmode E/MainActivity: onMainOrderMsgEvent:  finished
```

but the result as follows:

```
01-26 13:51:59.801 32643-32643/liufushihai.project.threadmode E/MainActivity: onMainOrderMsgEvent:  finished
01-26 13:51:59.801 32643-32643/liufushihai.project.threadmode E/MainActivity: onOtherMsgEvent:  finished
```

Do I understand correctly ? I’ll be appreciated to get a replay.